# Cant open apprequest dialog on facebook canvas after unity 5.0

Tags: canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

i am trying to get facebook apprequest to work on canvas but i am getting this error.;

```
    MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'UnityEngine.Screen.get_showCursor'. 
at Facebook.AsyncRequestFriendSelectorGet.ShowDialog (.FBResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Facebook.AsyncRequestDialogGet.CheckAndShowDialog (.FBResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
at Facebook.AsyncRequestString+<Start>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  (Filename: Line: -1)
```

Btw it is perfectly working on unity editor. I know current facebook sdk only supports unity 4.0 but maybe there is a workaround.